# Missing React Component Props with Jest test

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I have a component which looks like this

```
const Menu_ = props =>
 <div
  onClick={() => props.onClick("users")}
 />
```

and a Jest setup, like:

```
const tree = renderer
.create(<Menu_ page={""} onClick={page => null} />)
.toJSON();
```

I feel like I should be able to call

```
tree.props.onClick();
```

but... the renderer function from the 'react-test-renderer' package doesn't show me the props required props.

Is there a nice way to test; get access to the onClick prop; without touching my current code too much?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that what you're doing is creating component 
`.create(<Menu_ page={""} onClick={page => null} />)`
but then you turn this structure to JSON format:
`.toJSON();`

This structure can only hold pure data, not functions. You may want to take a look at `enzyme` and it render methods.